# Decoding a File-like object open in binary mode

Tags: python, utf-8, stream, decode

In python, given a file-like object that was opened in binary mode, what's the best way of converting it to a UTF8 decoded file-like object, without loading all contents to memory?

Comment: why not open if with `utf-8`?

Comment: because it's a temporary file which I get from a library and is already open

Answer (score 2):

You can get the StreamReader for a particular encoding and pass it the stream.  It will only return completely decoded code points.

```
#coding:utf8
import codecs
import io

# A file-like binary stream.
data = io.BytesIO('我是美国人。\n你是中国人。\n'.encode('utf8'))

# Get the UTF-8 StreamReader class and instantiate it on the data.
f = codecs.getreader('utf8')(data)

print(f.read(2))
f.seek(0)
for line in f:
    print(line,end='')
```

Output:

```
我是
我是美国人。
你是中国人。
```